# Animations on Mixamo not work

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I downloaded 2 animations from Mixamo called Idle and Walk_Forward. I created my controller with blend tree and it worked fine. But the problem is when I press W button, the character only move a short distance then back up to the orginal place where he start "Idle". Someone told me to download animation with "In place" option. So I tried then had another problem: The character just play animation but not move forward. About my component on character, I created RigidBody with Use Gravity, and the animation and character is humanoid type. How can I make those animations work ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an animation which animates in place then you'll have to add a characterController to make you're character actually move. The animation will only make it look like you'r player is moving. [Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/185226/c-movement-script-basic.html) is an example of how to move your character.

Answer (score 0):

Implement import of model settings and set "`Animation Type as humanoid`" in the `Rig tab`. Then press `Apply`. Now your animation would not repeat.